# Filebeat to Logstash timezone issue

Tags: timestamp, timezone, logstash, filebeat

Using Filebeat, and Logstash 7.9.
Customer logfiles have timestamps in local timezone.
Want to let Logstash know in which timezone filebeat lives.
Am able to do that via adding:

```
processors:
  - add_locale:
      format: abbreviation
```

in filebeat.yml, and in logstash filter using the event.timezone via:

```
    grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:logdate} %{GREEDYDATA:jsonmess}"}
    }
    date {
      match => ["logdate", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
      timezone => "{{ event.timezone }}"
    }
```

Problem is that filebeat options for the timezone format are "offset" and "abbrevation", but logstash expects only "canonical id's" !
How can i make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `offset` in the `timezone` option in the Logstash date filter.

For example, the following config will work without problems.

```
date {
    match => ["logdate", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    timezone => "-03:00"
}
```

Also, the way you are referencing the `event.timezone` field is wrong, you should use `%{[event][timezone}` and not `{{ event.timezone }}`

Try to change your config to

```
date {
    match => ["logdate", "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    timezone => "%{[event][timezone]}"
}
```